# Can a browser font list be obtained using PHP?

Tags: php, fonts

I just want to populate HTML font list inside a dropdown like:

```
<select>
  <option>Arial</option>
  <option>Verdana</option>
  .............
</select>
```

Is there any way to get all font list in array, so i can avoid writing of multiple options tags?

Thanks.

Comment: insert font list in database table and fetch wherever you want...

Comment: Thanks @Vicky is there any way using only php without database

Comment: The question is very vague. But I could imagine you want to offer different fonts so that the user can choose which to use for display? If so keep in mind that the fonts have to be available _on the client side_, so on the users computer. You have absolutely no control over that. So the question is: what do you really mean by "all fonts"?

Comment: If you're really asking how to get all the installed fonts ***in the browser***, that's a clientside issue, and plugins using flash do exists, but it has nothing to do whatsoever with PHP.

Comment: @adeneo it would be better to put all defaults fonts in an array and loop trough with that. My question is to avoid multiple options tag not with its available on client side or not.

Comment: @arkascha it would be better to put all defaults fonts in an array and loop trough with that. My question is to avoid multiple options tag not with its available on client side or not.

Comment: Then the question is even less clear. Sounds like you are asking: how can I create an array in php and loop over it to create output from its values. What is the problem in that? You create and array and use a foreach loop.  That is documented. So what is your specific question here?

Comment: @arkascha I just want to ask any other better way. seems i didn't describe my question clearly. BTW thanx a lot for you quick response.

Comment: [Various duplicates of this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=font+list+browser+javascript).